# WebGL 32bit floats in vertex shader

Tags: javascript, webgl, typed-arrays

Is there any way to get 32bit floats in WebGL shaders?
I have a lot of data packed into 4 unsigned bytes, and I would prefer to not split it into three bytes, because that would add many calculations on the client side.

E.g. for three pairs of packed data, I would obviously prefer this layout:

```
|u0 u1 u2 u3|u4 u5 u6 u7|u8 u9 u10 u11|
```

Than this:

```
|u0 u1 u2|u3 u4 u5|u6 u7 u8|u9 u10 u11|
```

Not only does this add a float which adds data sent through the bus, but it also makes me generate the 24bit numbers on the client instead of simply using a Float32Array which automatically handles 4 bytes.

If getting 32bit numbers isn't possible, is there any neat trick to generate 24bit numbers given a buffer, or must I loop over the bytes and encode each one (u1 + u2 * 256 + u3 * 65536)?

Comment: Beware, you only have 23 bits of precision with a float32. The trick here is to use the sign bit of the float32 to pack the last 24th bit.

Comment: I'm not understanding your question. Of course you can get 32bit floats in WebGL. Pretty much 99.999% of all samples use `Float32Array` and `gl.FLOAT` for their attributes and various kinds of `uniform float` uniforms. I have no idea what your `|u0 u1...` diagram is supposed to represent.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really understanding your question but if you want to upload bytes to WebGL why not just pass bytes?

```
var data = new Uint8Array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]);
var buf = gl.createBuffer();
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, buf);
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, data, gl.STATIC_DRAW);

...

gl.enableVertexAttribArray(someLoc);

var numComponents = 4;  // number of bytes to pull out each time
var type = gl.BYTE;     // BYTE goes from -128 to +127 or -1.0 to 1.0
                        // UNSIGNED_BYTE goes from 0 to 255 or 0.0 to 1.0
var normalize = false;  // false = use the value as is (-128 to +127 for BYTE,
                        // 0 to 255 for UNSIGNED_BYTE). 
                        // true = convert to -1.0 to +1.0 for BYTE or 0 to 1.0 for
                        // UNSIGNED_BYTE
var stride = 0;         // 0 means just advance numComponents * sizeof type.
var offset = 0;         // how far into your buffer to start.
gl.vertexAttribPointer(someLoc, numComponents, type, normalize, stride, offset);
```

If you're using `Uint8Array` or `Int8Array` then it doesn't seem like there's any special work to do to 'pack' in the values so having `numComponents = 3` is no harder or easier than `numComponents = 4`. You just set each component directly. Similarly there's no work to unpack them, GL will do it for you.

Comment: only 128 bit floating point textures can be fetched in vertex shader. Most modern GPUs allows to have single bytes, but the vast majority does not allows that and hence nor WebGL

Comment: it is implementation dependent, especially GL 3.x hardware has such limit, assuming it does work on every hardware just because works in your will cause code with undefined behaviour (wich is also the reason I guess the answer was not accepted)

Comment: Except WebGL REQUIRES this to work. It's part of the spec and part of the WebGL Conformance Tests. All GPUs WebGL runs on support this.

Comment: From my computer, My hardware does not support it, nor does it when running webgl. infact I don't have a full WebGL conformant PC, but I think majority of PCs are not fully conformant due to hardware details, apart recent pcs (4/5 years)

Comment: [Here's the test](https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/sdk/tests/conformance/attribs/gl-vertexattribpointer-offsets.html). I know of no GPUs that fail this test that run WebGL. If your GPU fails this test then I'm guessing WebGL is blacklisted for you and you unblacklisted it? The whole MO for WebGL is to run everywhere. Browsers aggressively blacklist GPUs that don't run it. But any DirectX 9 GPU should be able to run it no problem. It's possible ANGLE is expanding the data but that's beside the point really. From the POV of the WebGL user it should just work.